# MySQL 8.0.18 - ST_Area returns invalid value

Tags: mysql, spatial, mysql-8.0, geometry

I have a problem with `ST_Area` function in MySQL 8.0.16.

The result of the procedure call returns a different result than any library used to calculate the area of a polygon.

Example:

I have a GeoJSON with geometry like this:

```
{
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
            [
                [
                    16.91720977783202,
                    52.28469952907162
                ],
                [
                    16.910300407409657,
                    52.278608423688205
                ],
                [
                    16.919913444519032,
                    52.27753189128164
                ],
                [
                    16.91720977783202,
                    52.28469952907162
                ]
            ]
        ]
    }
```

The results of calulating area (in square meters) are:

- Google Maps: `250165.80185391553`
- [Turf](http://turfjs.org/docs/#area) library: `250152.24833417358`
- ST_Area(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(@poly_json)): `202818.55768974536`

First I was worried that GMaps (we got the coordinates from a map) is using some other projection, but it converts it into proper LatLng, so it shouldn't be a problem.

Do you have an idea why the result is so different between calculating area on the database and on the client?

Comment: Perhaps the lats and longs are swapped??

Comment: @RickJames No, I've checked this, example here is using [lng, lat] format, which is valid for GeoJSON standard.

Comment: Perhaps one or the other is not using spherical math??

Answer (score 1):

Please upgrade your MySQL version. In 8.0.32 the `st_area` returns:

```
mysql> set @poly = '{
'>         "type": "Polygon",
'>         "coordinates": [
'>             [
'>                 [
'>                     16.91720977783202,
'>                     52.28469952907162
'>                 ],
'>                 [
'>                     16.910300407409657,
'>                     52.278608423688205
'>                 ],
'>                 [
'>                     16.919913444519032,
'>                     52.27753189128164
'>                 ],
'>                 [
'>                     16.91720977783202,
'>                     52.28469952907162
'>                 ]
'>             ]
'>         ]
'>     }';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,00 sec)

mysql> select st_area(st_geomfromgeojson(@poly));
+------------------------------------+
| st_area(st_geomfromgeojson(@poly)) |
+------------------------------------+
|                  250662.8501818171 |
+------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```